# Filter data after join using PIG

Tags: apache-pig

I would like to filter the records after two files are joined.

The file BX-Books.csv contains the book data. and the file BX-Book-Ratings.csv contains books rating data where *ISBN* is the common column from both the files. The inner join betweeb the files is done using the this column. 
I would like to get the books that are published in the year 2002.

I have used the following script but i am getting 0 records.

```
grunt> BookXRecords = LOAD '/user/pradeep/BX-Books.csv'  USING PigStorage(';') AS (ISBN:chararray,BookTitle:chararray,BookAuthor:chararray,YearOfPublication:chararray, Publisher:chararray,ImageURLS:chararray,ImageURLM:chararray,ImageURLL:chararray);
grunt> BookXRating = LOAD '/user/pradeep/BX-Book-Ratings.csv'  USING PigStorage(';') AS (user:chararray,ISBN:chararray,rating:chararray);
grunt> BxJoin = JOIN BookXRecords BY ISBN, BookXRating BY ISBN;
grunt> BxJoin_Mod = FOREACH BxJoin GENERATE $0 AS ISBN, $1, $2, $3, $4;
grunt> FLTRBx2002 = FILTER BxJoin_Mod BY $3 == '2002';
```

Comment: What does "describe BxJoin_Mod;" output? Also do you have data that has YearOfPublication as 2002 ?

Comment: grunt> DESCRIBE BxJoin_Mod;                                                                                                                 
BxJoin_Mod: {ISBN: chararray,BookXRecords::BookTitle: chararray,BookXRecords::BookAuthor: chararray,BookXRecords::YearOfPublication: chararr
ay,BookXRecords::Publisher: chararray}

Comment: Yes, I have data that has YearOfPublication == 2002

Comment: Please check the answer I have posted, I tried and it did work.

Comment: could you please let me know if this worked for you ?

Comment: I realized that the file had values enclosed with double quotes.  FILTER BxJoin_Mod BY $3 == '"2002"'; worked for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a test.csv and test-rating.csv and a Pig script that works out of them. It worked perfectly fine.

**test.csv**

```
1;abc;author1;2002
2;xyz;author2;2003
```

**test-rating.csv**

```
user1;1;3
user2;2;5
```

**Pig Script :**

```
A = LOAD 'test.csv' USING PigStorage(';') AS (ISBN:chararray,BookTitle:chararray,BookAuthor:chararray,YearOfPublication:chararray);
describe A;
dump A;

B = LOAD 'test-rating.csv' USING PigStorage(';') AS (user:chararray,ISBN:chararray,rating:chararray);
describe B;
dump B;

C = JOIN A BY ISBN, B BY ISBN;
describe C;
dump C;

D = FOREACH C GENERATE $0 as ISBN,$1,$2,$3;
describe D;
dump D;

E = FILTER D BY $3 == '2002';
describe E;
dump E;
```

**Output:**

```
A: {ISBN: chararray,BookTitle: chararray,BookAuthor: chararray,YearOfPublication: chararray}
(1,abc,author1,2002)
(2,xyz,author2,2003)
B: {user: chararray,ISBN: chararray,rating: chararray}
(user1,1,3)
(user2,2,5)
C: {A::ISBN: chararray,A::BookTitle: chararray,A::BookAuthor: chararray,A::YearOfPublication: chararray,B::user: chararray,B::ISBN: chararray,B::rating: chararray}
(1,abc,author1,2002,user1,1,3)
(2,xyz,author2,2003,user2,2,5)
D: {ISBN: chararray,A::BookTitle: chararray,A::BookAuthor: chararray,A::YearOfPublication: chararray}
(1,abc,author1,2002)
(2,xyz,author2,2003)
E: {ISBN: chararray,A::BookTitle: chararray,A::BookAuthor: chararray,A::YearOfPublication: chararray}
(1,abc,author1,2002)
```

Comment: While it works, what was the point in naming the columns if you're not going to use them after joining?

Answer (score 0):

Requirement: Get the books that are published in the year 2002.

It is not required to have 2 data set. 
Only with the "BookXRecords", this can be achieved.

```
grunt>BookXRecords = LOAD '/user/pradeep/BX-Books.csv'  USING PigStorage(';') AS (ISBN:chararray,BookTitle:chararray,BookAuthor:chararray,YearOfPublication:chararray, Publisher:chararray,ImageURLS:chararray,ImageURLM:chararray,ImageURLL:chararray);
grunt>A=FILTER BookXRecords BY year ='2002';
grunt>dump A;
```